# Conf files and static files in a deb package

Tags: ubuntu, debian, packaging, deb, debhelper

I'm using dh_help to build a package template and trying to follow the ubuntu and debian packaging guides for creating a binary package.

How do I tell debuild which file is a conf file and should go for example to /etc/mypkg.conf ?
I've tried to put it under mypkg-0.1/etc/mypkg/fname.conf but debuild ignores it.
The debian guide says all files under etc/ are treated automatically as conf files but it doesn't work for me (http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guid...ml#s-conffiles).
I've tried putting the conf file under mypkg-1.0/etc/mypkg.conf and under mypkg-1.0/debain/etc/mypkg.conf but it is not included. I also tried to list the file in conffiles but I'm getting an error that it can't be found when building the package.

I also don't understand how to include static files in the package.
Do I have to use the install file to list all the files and folders?
I thought that putting everything with the full path under the mypkgs-0.1 folder should work like it does when using dpkg manually.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As viraptor said you can put an install command for each file into your `debian/rules` to install the files into the debian/pkgname directory.

Or you can use a [`debian/install`](http://www.debian.org/doc/maint-guide/ch-dother.en.html#s-install) file to simply list all the files (or just directories) and have a dh_install command in your `debian/rules` to do it for you.

It seems you are a little confused about how packages are built and which files are included. This is extremely generalized, but when the `debian/rules` script compiles a program using standard `./configure && make && make install` method, it instructs the `make install` to install the files to `debian/pkgname` instead of `/`. Then it knows that everything under `debian/pkgname` is what should be in the final .deb. If the `make install` step doesn't put everything in the correct location, then the `debian/rules` script needs to do that. Previously it seems calling `install ...` from `debian/rules` to copy the files to the `debian/pkgname` directory was common but now using a `debian/install` file seems to be the preferred method.

Comment: How is `make install` instructed to install into `debian/packagename`? I get always `debian/tmp` (but I have no special configuration).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to include the package version if you install files via the standard debhelper / `debian/rules` file. Instead, in the install step do:

```
install -cm 644 fname.conf $(CURDIR)/debian/mypkg/etc/mypkg/fname.conf
```

And it should be included properly.